# Reverse not working, tranny noisy

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, silverado, 4l60e

I thought I was stopped and put vehicle in reverse. Strange noise now no reverse and tranny whines and seems to shift hard on drive gears. Its an '04 Silverado 2×4, v6, 4.3l had no problems prior that I can think of. Have I fried my tranny?

Comment: Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the truck for a ride by placing the gear selector all the way down into 1st gear. Vehicle should start going. Get the engine up a little higher than you'd normally hear/feel it shift and click it up one gear to 2nd. You may not feel it shift. If you don't, click it up into drive and see if the shift happens and the rpms drop down fairly dramatically. Again, drive the vehicle faster, getting it up so the RPMs are somewhere around 3000-3500rpm and then shift it up again.

If you do not feel it shift when it goes into 2nd, nor does it shift up into over-drive, your sunshell is shot (broke sunshell = missing Rev/2nd/OD). This is one of the weak points of the 4L60e transmission. It can be rebuilt, but there will have to be work done to it. If you do get it rebuilt, consider getting a Beast Sunshell rather than putting a stock unit back into the tranny. You'll most likely run into the same issue again with an OEM sunshell unit. The Beast isn't that much more money for the part itself, but be aware labor is not going to be cheap. Doing a complete rebuild at this point is a VERY good option.

Comment: I'm curious as to how this happened. I read that there's this "reverse inability" thing that prevents the veh from shifting into rev from drive until a certain rpm is reached. Would my veh have this feature and if so, what did I do?

Comment: What do you do? If it's broke, get it fixed. Not anything anyone wants to hear, but is the way it is. I own an '06 Silvy. I'm dreading the day when the tranny decides to let go. I don't know for sure about the "reverse inability" function (it could very well have it, I'm not sure). If it does have it, it might only function at over certain speeds. You might have just been in a "sweet spot" which allowed it to shift while rolling, which could have caused the damage. All in all, without reverse by itself, there's some kind of damage. You'll need to get it worked on to find out for sure.

Comment: Right on. It may be easier to replace the tranny as opposed to fix this one. What ones are compatible with my truck? Could I use one from an 8 cyl 4×4 Chev z71 '99 or '00?

Comment: No. You'd need one from a 4x2 Chevy or GMC 1500 truck, though year coverage on it should be pretty broad. The reason is the tail shaft is completely different. I'm not sure if one from a small truck or car would work, though the 4L60e was used in about everything. I'd highly recommend you **NOT** get a used one unless you are only doing it as a stopgap measure (something to get you by for a few thousand miles until you can get a rebuilt one put in).